# true isometric projection with opengl

Tags: c++, opengl, projection, isometric

Is there a simple way to have isometric projection?

I mean [the true isometric projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometric_projection), not the general orthogonal projection.

(Isometric projection happens only when projections of unit X, Y and Z vectors are equally long and angles between them are exactly 120 degrees.)

Comment: duplicate of http://www.allegro.cc/forums/thread/600737

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try using [gluLookAt](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/)

```
glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();

/* use this length so that camera is 1 unit away from origin */
double dist = sqrt(1 / 3.0);

gluLookAt(dist, dist, dist,  /* position of camera */
          0.0,  0.0,  0.0,   /* where camera is pointing at */
          0.0,  1.0,  0.0);  /* which direction is up */
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

glBegin(GL_LINES);

glColor3d(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glVertex3d(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glVertex3d(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);

glColor3d(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
glVertex3d(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glVertex3d(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);

glColor3d(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
glVertex3d(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glVertex3d(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

glEnd();

glFlush();
```

Results in

[image]

We can draw a cube to check that parallel lines are indeed parallel

```
glPushMatrix();
glTranslated(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
glColor3d(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
glutWireCube(1);
glPopMatrix();
```

[image]

Comment: This won't give you an isometric projection, because parallel lines, say along the x and y axes, won't appear parallel, when they actually should.

Comment: look at the picture on the wikipedia article that was linked too in the question, this looks exactly like that projection. Any parallel lines will appear parallel because this is a Orthographic projection (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographic_projection). The x and y axes are not parallel.

Comment: I don't mean the x and y axes are parallel, but that lines parallel to the x axis should appear parallel in an isometric projection (and I don't think they will in yours), and similarly in the y direction.

Comment: Whoops, my bad. I missed that you were *only* calling gluLookAt. +1 now.

Answer (score 9):

An isometric projection is just a matter of using an orthographic projection with a specific rotation angle.

You should be able to choose any of the 8 potential orientations, with a orthographic projection, and get a perfect isometric view of your model.  Just follow the math in your referenced Wiki article for setting up the view matrix, and do an orthographic projection for your projection matrix, and you're all set.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I'm not quite grokking the math correctly, but couldn't you just position your camera as it explains in that Wikipedia link and use a standard orthogonal projection?

Even if it's not the same, the projection stack is entirely up to you.

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
// your isometric matrix here (see math on Wikipedia)
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to use GLU, here is bare bones using glOrtho

```
void gl_enter_2_5d_mode (void)
{
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glPushMatrix();

    glLoadIdentity();

    double scale = 50;
    glOrtho(-scale,
            scale,
            -scale * 0.7,
            scale * 0.7,
            -scale,
            scale);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glPushMatrix();

    glLoadIdentity();

    glRotatef(35.264f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glRotatef(-45.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
}

void gl_leave_2_5d_mode (void)
{
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glPopMatrix();

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glPopMatrix();
}

then draw a cube in it

void cube (double size)
{
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);

    glVertex3f(size,size,size);
    glVertex3f(-size,size,size);
    glVertex3f(-size,-size,size);
    glVertex3f(size,-size,size);

    glVertex3f(size,size,-size);
    glVertex3f(-size,size,-size);
    glVertex3f(-size,-size,-size);
    glVertex3f(size,-size,-size);

    glVertex3f(size,size,size);
    glVertex3f(size,-size,size);
    glVertex3f(size,-size,-size);
    glVertex3f(size,size,-size);

    glVertex3f(-size,size,size);
    glVertex3f(-size,-size,size);
    glVertex3f(-size,-size,-size);
    glVertex3f(-size,size,-size);

    glVertex3f(size,size,size);
    glVertex3f(-size,size,size);
    glVertex3f(-size,size,-size);
    glVertex3f(size,size,-size);

    glVertex3f(size,-size,size);
    glVertex3f(-size,-size,size);
    glVertex3f(-size,-size,-size);
    glVertex3f(size,-size,-size);

    glEnd();
}

void test (void)
{
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    cube(1.0);
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK,GL_FILL);
}
```

and call something like this

```
gl_enter_2_5d_mode()
test()
gl_leave_2_5d_mode()
```

should you want to toggle between 2d and 2.5d (so you can draw your UI) then I have similar functions to enter and leave 2d mode e.g.

```
void gl_init_2d_mode (void)
{
    /*
     * Enable Texture Mapping
     */
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    /*
     * Enable alpha blending for sprites
     */
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    /*
     * Setup our viewport
     */
    glViewport(0, 0, game.video_pix_width,
               game.video_pix_height);

    /*
     * Make sure we're changing the model view and not the projection
     */
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glPushMatrix();

    /*
     * Reset the view
     */
    glLoadIdentity();

    gl_init_fbo();
}

void gl_enter_2d_mode (void)
{
    /*
     * Change to the projection matrix and set our viewing volume.
     */
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glPushMatrix();

    /*
     * Reset the view
     */
    glLoadIdentity();

    /*
     * 2D projection
     */
    glOrtho(0,
             game.video_gl_width, game.video_gl_height,
             0, -1200.0, 1200.0);

    /*
     * Make sure we're changing the model view and not the projection
     */
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glPushMatrix();

    /*
     * Reset the view
     */
    glLoadIdentity();
}
```