# Isometric view in OpenGL

Tags: python, python-3.x, opengl, view, isometric

I am trying to understand why the isometric view is not correct. The most accurate representation is at 55 degrees with the vertical axis, and 45 with the horizontal. In the mcve there are two points who should be aligned at 45 degrees on each axis. I have set up a camera movement based in the sphere algebra definition. The edges of the planes should coincide, but they do not.

MCVE:

```py
from OpenGL.GL import glClear, GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, glEnable, GL_DEPTH_TEST, glMatrixMode, GL_PROJECTION, \
    glLoadIdentity, glOrtho, glClearColor, GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT, GL_MODELVIEW, glLineWidth, glBegin, glColor, glVertex, \
    glEnd, glPointSize, GL_POINT_SMOOTH, GL_POINTS, GL_BLEND, glBlendFunc, GL_SRC_ALPHA, \
    GL_QUADS, glDisable, GL_LINES, GL_LINE_LOOP, glDepthMask, GL_FALSE, GL_TRUE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA
from OpenGL.GLU import gluLookAt
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QOpenGLWidget
from math import sin, cos, radians


class Renderizador(QOpenGLWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.dx = 0
        self.dy = 0
        self.dz = 0
        self.theta = 405
        self.phi = 45
        self.x = sin(radians(self.theta)) * cos(radians(self.phi)) + self.dx
        self.z = sin(radians(self.theta)) * sin(radians(self.phi)) + self.dz
        self.y = cos(radians(self.theta)) + self.dy
        self.vertices_vertical = ((100, 100, 0), (-100, 100, 0), (-100, 0, 0), (100, 0, 0))
        self.vertices_vertical_debajo = ((100, 0, 0), (-100, 0, 0), (-100, -100, 0), (100, -100, 0))
        self.vertices_horizontal = ((100, 0, 0), (100, 0, 100), (-100, 0, 100), (-100, 0, 0))
        self.vertices_horizontal_detras = ((100, 0, 0), (100, 0, -100), (-100, 0, -100), (-100, 0, 0))
        self.vertices_borde_v = ((100, 100, 0), (100, -100, 0), (-100, -100, 0), (-100, 100, 0))
        self.vertices_borde_h = ((100, 0, 100), (-100, 0, 100), (-100, 0, -100), (100, 0, -100))
        self.puntos = [("a", 1, 1, 1), ("b", 10, 10, 10)]

    def recalcular(self):
        self.x = sin(radians(self.theta)) * cos(radians(self.phi)) + self.dx
        self.z = sin(radians(self.theta)) * sin(radians(self.phi)) + self.dz
        self.y = cos(radians(self.theta)) + self.dy
        gluLookAt(self.x, self.y, self.z, self.dx, self.dy, self.dz, 0, 1, 0)
        self.update()

    def dibujar_planos(self):
        glEnable(GL_BLEND)
        glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)
        glDepthMask(GL_FALSE)
        glBegin(GL_QUADS)
        glColor(1, 0, 0, 0.5)
        for vertex in range(4):
            glVertex(self.vertices_horizontal_detras[vertex])
        glColor(0, 1, 0, 0.5)
        for vertex in range(4):
            glVertex(self.vertices_vertical_debajo[vertex])
        glColor(0, 1, 0, 0.5)
        for vertex in range(4):
            glVertex(self.vertices_vertical[vertex])
        glColor(1, 0, 0, 0.5)
        for vertex in range(4):
            glVertex(self.vertices_horizontal[vertex])
        glEnd()
        glDepthMask(GL_TRUE)
        glDisable(GL_BLEND)
        glLineWidth(1)
        glColor(0.2, 1, 0.2, 0.5)
        glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP)
        for vertex in range(4):
            glVertex(self.vertices_borde_v[vertex])
        glColor(1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.5)
        glEnd()
        glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP)
        for vertex in range(4):
            glVertex(self.vertices_borde_h[vertex])
        glEnd()

    @staticmethod
    def dibujar_ejes():
        glLineWidth(3)
        glBegin(GL_LINES)
        # X ROJO
        glColor(1, 0, 0)
        glVertex(0, 0, 0)
        glVertex(10, 0, 0)
        # Y VERDE
        glColor(0, 1, 0)
        glVertex(0, 0, 0)
        glVertex(0, 10, 0)
        # Z AZUL
        glColor(0, 0, 1)
        glVertex(0, 0, 0)
        glVertex(0, 0, 10)
        glEnd()

    def dibujar_punto(self):

        glColor(0, 0, 0, 0)
        glPointSize(4)
        glEnable(GL_POINT_SMOOTH)
        glBegin(GL_POINTS)
        for i in range(len(self.puntos)):
            glVertex(self.puntos[i][1], self.puntos[i][3], self.puntos[i][2])
        glEnd()

        # self.x = sin(radians(self.theta)) * cos(radians(self.phi)) + self.dx
        # self.z = sin(radians(self.theta)) * sin(radians(self.phi)) + self.dz
        # self.y = cos(radians(self.theta)) + self.dy
        # gluLookAt(self.x, self.y, self.z, self.dx, self.dy, self.dz, 0, 1, 0)
        self.update()

    def initializeGL(self):
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
        glLoadIdentity()
        glOrtho(100, -100, -100, 100, -500, 150)
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)

    def paintGL(self):
        glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 0)
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        glLoadIdentity()
        up = 1
        if self.theta == 360:
            up = -1
        gluLookAt(self.x, self.y, self.z, self.dx, self.dy, self.dz, 0, up, 0)
        self.dibujar_ejes()
        self.dibujar_planos()
        self.dibujar_punto()

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_W:
            self.theta -= 5
        elif event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_A:
            self.phi -= 5
        elif event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_S:
            self.theta += 5
        elif event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_D:
            self.phi += 5
        elif event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Q:
            self.dz += 1
        elif event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_E:
            self.dz -= 1
        elif event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Left:
            self.dx -= 1
        elif event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Up:
            self.dy += 1
        elif event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Right:
            self.dx += 1
        elif event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Down:
            self.dy -= 1

        if self.theta < 360:
            self.theta = 360
        if self.theta > 540:
            self.theta = 540
        if self.phi >= 360:
            self.phi -= 360
        if self.phi < 0:
            self.phi += 360

        self.x = sin(radians(self.theta)) * cos(radians(self.phi)) + self.dx
        self.z = sin(radians(self.theta)) * sin(radians(self.phi)) + self.dz
        self.y = cos(radians(self.theta)) + self.dy

        ui.actualizar()
        self.update()
        super().keyPressEvent(event)


class UiVentana(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(UiVentana, self).__init__(parent)
        ventana.resize(1500, 1015)

        self.widget_central = QtWidgets.QWidget(ventana)
        self.Renderizador = Renderizador(self.widget_central)
        self.Renderizador.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1000, 1000))
        self.Renderizador.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.StrongFocus)

        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget_central)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1110, 49, 160, 20))
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget_central)
        self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1010, 70, 111, 16))
        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget_central)
        self.label_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1130, 70, 130, 16))

        self.label_5.setText("X: Y: Z:")
        self.label_6.setText("Ángulo vertical:")
        self.label_7.setText("Ángulo horizontal:")

        ventana.setCentralWidget(self.widget_central)
        ventana.show()

    def actualizar(self):
        x = round(100 * (sin(radians(self.Renderizador.theta)) * cos(radians(self.Renderizador.phi)))
                  + self.Renderizador.dx, 2)
        z = round(100 * (sin(radians(self.Renderizador.theta)) * sin(radians(self.Renderizador.phi)))
                  + self.Renderizador.dz, 2)
        y = round(100 * (cos(radians(self.Renderizador.theta))) + self.Renderizador.dy, 2)
        theta = self.Renderizador.theta - 360
        phi = self.Renderizador.phi
        if x == -0:
            x = 0
        if y == -0:
            y = 0
        if z == -0:
            z = 0
        self.label_5.setText("X: {} Y: {} Z: {}".format(x, z, y))
        self.label_6.setText("Ángulo vertical: " + str(theta))
        self.label_7.setText("Ángulo horizontal: " + str(phi))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    ventana = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = UiVentana()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: If (dx, dy, dz) == (0, 0, 0), then x, y, and z have to have exactly same value.

Comment: @Rabbid76 they are set initially at 0, the problem is with the angles I think

Comment: No, when the angle is 55 respectively 45, the x, y and z have not exactly the same value. Of course the angle of theta is the issue.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Oh I see, so the three values should be equal at 45 degrees?

Comment: No, `phi` has to be 45°, but `theta` has to be something like 54,6°. At the moment my math is somehow confused.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Ohhhh I saw the 54,6 number in another question, i will search

Comment: I found this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_angle

Comment: You've to find the angle `theta` where `sin(theta) * 0.707213578` is equal `cos(theta)`. - `self.theta = 54.735610317245345684622999669982` = arcos(1/sqrt(3))

Comment: Here there is another important angle: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometric_projection#Overview

Comment: Here is one answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509551/how-to-render-with-isometric-perspective

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a perfect isometric view, the point of view has to be on a diagonal of a cube. This means if the target of the view is (0, 0, 0) then the absolute value of the x, y and z coordinate of the eye position has to be equal.

When you look at the formula which calculates x, y, and z:

> ```py
> self.x = sin(radians(self.theta)) * cos(radians(self.phi)) + self.dx
> self.z = sin(radians(self.theta)) * sin(radians(self.phi)) + self.dz
> self.y = cos(radians(self.theta)) + self.dy
> ```

This means you've to find a `phi` and `theta` that result in equal x, y and z.

For phi this is easy. Phi is only use do calculate x and z. x depends on `cos(phi)` and z depends on `sin(phi)` since `sin(45) == cos(45)`, `phi` has to be 45°.

`sin(45)` is equal `1/sqrt(2)`.

So it has to be found a `theta`, where x, y and z are equal when

> ```
> x = sin(theta) * 1/sqrt(2)
> z = sin(theta) * 1/sqrt(2)
> y = cos(theta)
> ```

This means

> ```
> sin(theta) * 1/sqrt(2) = cos(theta)
> ```

From [Pythagoras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem) we know that:

> ```
> cos²(theta) + sin²(theta) = 1
> ```

So

`sin(theta) = cos(theta) * sqrt(2)` and `sin²(theta) = 1 - cos²(theta)`

`1 - cos²(theta) = cos²(theta) * 2`

`1 = cos(theta) * sqrt(3)`

`theta = acos(1/sqrt(3))`

At the end `phi` and `theta` have to be:

```py
self.phi   = 45
self.theta = 54.735610317245345684622999669982
```