# OpenGL isometric projection clipping

Tags: opengl, jogl, projection, clipping, isometric

I am using this neat trick from another Stack Overflow question: [True Isometric Projection with OpenGL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1059219/1400554) to setup an isometric projection. If I draw just outline with lines everything is fine [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1059219/1400554) but if I draw polygons they get clipped and so lines [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDVMt.png).

[image: Correct]      [image: Clipped]

#### Code to setup projection:

```
    pmv.glMatrixMode(PMVMatrix.GL_PROJECTION);
    pmv.glLoadIdentity();
    float dist = (float)Math.sqrt(1 / 3.0f);
    pmv.gluLookAt(dist, dist, dist,
              0.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,
              0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f);
```

**NOTE:** I am using JOGL, so it might be a possible bug there; other than that, no culling, depth test enabled and depthrange for offsetting lines/polys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By closer look at frustum near and far planes you can see they are set badly

```
    N: Plane[ [ 0.57735026, 0.57735026, 0.57735026 ], 0.0], 
    F: Plane[ [ -0.57735026, -0.57735026, -0.57735026 ], 1.9999998]],
```

solution is easy set ortho projection first with correct near/far values and then multiply it with lookat function matrix

```
    pmv.glMatrixMode(PMVMatrix.GL_PROJECTION);
    pmv.glLoadIdentity();
    pmv.glOrthof(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
    float dist = (float)Math.sqrt(1 / 3.0f);
    pmv.gluLookAt(dist, dist, dist,
              0.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,
              0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f);
```

results in:

```
    N: Plane[ [ -0.57735026, -0.57735026, -0.57735026 ], 1.9999998], 
    F: Plane[ [ 0.57735026, 0.57735026, 0.57735026 ], 0.0]],
```